# Google maps : Current location blue bubble not shown , current location button not working in older device

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am doing a project using google maps.The current location is shown in new devices , but is not shown in older 2.3 device.How do i make the current location visible in the older device.

My code:

```
public void initialiseMap()
    {
        if (googleMap == null) {
             googleMap = ( (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();


       }
        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        else
        {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
//          UiSettings uiSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
//          uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);



            }
            //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(current_latitude, current_longitude);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        //googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11.5f));

        }
```

I have heard using a support libarary would help..Can someone clarify that point too pls.

Comment: I have added the support library.

Answer (score 0):

`Not shown in older 2.3 device`.

Unless for very specific purposes, you should instead start developing for Android 4.0+. It's possible you're writing code that's not available on 2.3 devices.

Comment: Can you suggest what changes to make in my code posted above?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All I can really suggest is that you move away from Android 2.3. But should you really want it to work on 2.3, you can find an external library/API that is compatible.

Comment: How come it works paritally.Everything except the blue bubble and the current location button is fine.

Comment: Could be a multitude of things. Changes in the program/API from 2.3 to 4.0+, hardware, etc. Again, I strongly suggest to further develop for 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Blue dot appearance depends on your device being able to localize itself.

**Make sure you turn on the GPS and have related settings enabled in My location part of Settings app:** "Use wireless networks" and "Use GPS satellites".